# Why didn't Yoda further investigate why Qui Gon Jin's Force Ghost screamed "Anakin, nooo!", and simulataneously felt a disturbance in the Force?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones, anakin-skywalker, yoda

Why didn't Yoda further investigate why Qui Gon Jin's Force Ghost screamed "Anakin, nooo!", and simultaneously felt a disturbance in the Force when Anakin killed the Sand People?

Comment: Coz he was senile and forgot, or coz he got distracted by a butterfly and forgot, or coz its one more gaping hole in the universe we love so much.

Comment: I guess people shouted "Noooooooooooo" so often back then that people didn't really see it as being a big deal

Comment: Yoda probably feels a lot of disturbances in the force. It's not like Anakin was occupying all his attention, either. While central to the plot for the viewer, if you think about the world from Yoda's point of view... Anakin is a minor blip (well, initially, obviously becoming Vader changed that).

Comment: Well, Yoda said later to Mace Windu : "Pain, suffering, death I feel. Something terrible has happened. Young Skywalker is in pain. Terrible pain." So he knew Anakin is in trouble. And then the Clone Wars began and Anakin's pain became a lot less important.

Comment: Yoda doesn't care about Sandpeople. Racist.

Comment: Because Yoda is a Sith.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the film's official novelisation, Yoda had a whole bunch of stuff going on in that scene. Notably, he was extremely surprised to learn that survival of the spirit *after death* was possible.

> It was Qui-Gon. Yoda knew that it was Qui-Gon. But Qui-Gon was dead,
>   had become one with the Force! One could not retain consciousness and
>   sense of self in that state; one could not speak from beyond the
>   grave.
>
> But Yoda had heard the ghostly call, and in his deep meditative state,
>   his thoughts focused as precisely as they had ever been, the Jedi
>   Master knew that he had not been mistaken.
>
> He wanted to focus on that, then, perhaps to try to follow that call
>   back to the ghostly source, but he could not, overwhelmed again by the
>   surge of rage and pain and… power.
>
> He made a noise and lurched forward, then came out of his trance as
>   his door opened and Mace Windu rushed in. “What is it?” Mace asked.
>   “Pain. Suffering. Death! I fear something terrible has happened. Young
>   Skywalker is in pain. Terrible pain.”
>
> He didn’t tell Mace the rest of it, that somehow Anakin’s rush of
>   agony manifesting in the Force had tapped into the spirit of the dead
>   Jedi Master who had discovered him. Too much was happening here. That
>   disembodied familiar voice hung profoundly in Yoda’s thoughts. For if
>   it was true, if he had heard what he was sure he had heard… - <sub><sup>[Attack of the Clones - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones_(novel))</sup></sub>

Since the next scene takes us straight into the action on Geonosis (followed by a jump straight into Revenge of the Sith, several years later) we're forced to conclude that Yoda did ask Anakin about it, and Anakin just outright lied to him:

> Palpatine and Padmé were the only ones who knew about the revenge he
>   had taken. Padmé had been horrified as much by Anakin’s grief as by
>   what he had done; Palpatine called the killings “regrettable.” - <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith - Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

Comment: Odd. Why would Palpatine know about Anakin slaughtering a sand people tribe?

Comment: @Xantec - Because Anakin and Palpatine are big buddies off-screen.

Comment: @xantec - "*And he [Anakin] wasn’t even sure he wanted one. He couldn’t let himself think about this. Just as he didn’t let himself think about the dead on Tatooine. He put his hand to his eyes, trying to rub away the memory. “You promised we would never talk about that again.” “And we won’t. Just as we need never speak of what has happened here today.” It was as though the shadow itself spoke kindly. “I [Palpatine] have always kept your secrets, have I not?”*"

Comment: @Richard Did Anakin draw upon the Dark Side when killed the sand folks?

Comment: @JoshSchwarzzeskywalker - Ask it as a new question

Comment: @Richard I really need to read the novelisations, there apparently is a plethora of information I was unaware of in them that is not in the movies.

Comment: @JoshSchwarzzeskywalker - Pfft. Reading is for [nerds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRsPheErBj8).